# Time Machine says "Next backup: When disk is connected" even though disk is connected

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, high-sierra

After upgrading to MacOS High Sierra, Time Machine now says "Next backup: When disk is connected", even though the disk is indeed already connected. Also, automatic backups are still being performed.

I already tried doing a [full reset of Time Machine](http://pondini.org/TM/A4.html)* but that didn't fix it.

[image: Time Machine screenshot]

*Note:* As at 2019, The Pondini site has been archived to http://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/Home.html Existing links, if you find them can be added manually, to make the above link into http://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/A4.html

Comment: Yes, I've got the same issue on a 2013 Mac Pro. Interestingly, I've noted that Time Machine is doing a full backup each time and therefore the disk is full within a day.

Comment: @Mark, did this start happening to you after you upgraded to High Sierra? And does reformatting the Time Machine drive and starting the backups from scratch fix your problems?

Comment: I am seeing this error as well.  I have done a clean install of High Sierra, and am using a freshly formatted disk for the backups.  Time Machine gets one backup done and then switches into thinking the disk is no longer connected.  If I disable and re-enable the automatic backups then it schedules another backup.  The disk is connected and functional.  This exact same setup worked with Sierra.

Comment: Same problem here..